# Including other people's answer into your own accepted answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I have seen the author of an accepted answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48501484/5847976)) copy/paste (with credit) the content of a later answer on the same question inside his own with the rationale "the idea of SO is to have the best answer at the top" which I am reading as "let's merge all the good answers into the accepted one". Both answers (the accepted and the one that was copy/pasted) were good and complementary but the copy/pasting had no added value.

My question is: Is that behavior acceptable and/or desirable?

(My two cents being that, to me, <s>it seems to be nothing more than an attempt to "steal" upvotes</s> (Edit: considering the author's reaction to this question I now believe it wasn't) as there's no added value from the merging and having multiple good answers to a question is acceptable.)

Comment: That is not OK, not even sure if the attribution is enough.

Comment: In my opinion, you should only do this (with proper attribution, of course) if you make the answer a community wiki. That way, you indicate this is a group effort, and not the answer of a single person (and there's no longer a motivation to steal upvotes, since no-one's getting any rep).

Comment: We have votes to make the more useful answer travel to the top. If we were going to put all the answers together, having multiple answers to vote independently woulnd't make much sense.

Comment: I had one of my answers included into the top answer by a moderator before so presumably this is officially sanctioned in some circumstances https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103053/how-aggressively-should-we-maintain-and-improve-very-popular-questions this case is of course different as there are only two answers anyway.

Comment: "That is not OK, not even sure if the attribution is enough" @rene

Comment: @Chris_Rands I'm old but not so short of memory that I need to be pinged about my own comments.

Comment: @rene I was including another person's comment in my own comment with attribution

Comment: That joke is beyond me ;)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is not OK. While it's true that there will often be very similar (and sometimes nearly identical) code implementations for certain solutions to problems, the blatant copying of someone else's answer simply defeats the purpose of having multiple people answer the question.

Answers that contain content from other posts or answers should only do so if that content is supplementary or ancillary, and should typically serve to *enrich* an explanation or comparison of solutions. They should not be a "oh by the way someone else did it better so here it is in my answer too" blurb. This would be a bit like me writing a book about wizards and also including the entire Harry Potter series in it (albeit on a lesser scale); the same problem with my action applies.

The appropriate thing here is to address this with the OP, and for the OP to remove the edit containing the other answerer's code from his post. Both of these steps have now been completed without too much fanfare.

Answer (score 7):

As the subject of the post, I would like @Tai's answer to be accepted ahead of mine, but that's not possible. Can an administrator, or other users, vote to have his answer accepted?

Otherwise, the voting system doesn't really work to bring "the best answer to the top". Similarly, I've seen answers with negative reputation accepted (sometimes with, often without, explanation in comments).

**To be clear**: Even now, to the author of the original post, it may not be clear what the difference is between my response and @Tai's (mine makes a new array, and @Tai's solution is in-place). I added @Tai's solution as in-place alternative and explained it as such. Now the next question is: should people be adding explanations to other people's solutions, or would this break another rule of etiquette? To me, adding an explanation of the difference in one post and not the other may be insufficient.

Comment: You can flag the post for moderator attention to explain that you want to delete your answer, because you now realize it's not a good answer, but that you can't, because it's accepted.  Moderators will generally comply with such requests so long as it's clear the author isn't trying to vandalize their own useful content.

Comment: Don't worry too much about which answer is accepted, several people including the asker considered your answer to be good and people will most certainly also see Tai's answer too so there isn't that much to worry about. And about your last point, comments are there to do precisely that: adding some precisions, suggesting corrections, asking for more info etc ...

Comment: @jadsq, i suggested an edit which was rejected:

This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.
This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.

The edit was: "This solution is in-place. If you need to create a new array, see [@jp_data_analysis' answer][1]."

I added a reversed statement in my solution. Is the moderation being a bit paranoid?

Comment: Your suggested edit - making each of the two answers indicate how they differ from each other and why you might prefer the other - was a sensible thing to do, in my view. Since I have enough rep to make the edit unilaterally myself, I've done so.

Comment: As for getting the accepted answer changed, that's not something the mods can do; they have the power to *outright delete* accepted answers, which is sometimes helpful, but that's not the appropriate outcome here. Beyond that, the choice of which answer is accepted lies entirely with the asker. It doesn't hurt to [politely ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48501432/copy-values-except-0-from-array-2-to-array-1/48501484#comment84078011_48501432), though.

Comment: *"should people be adding explanations to other people's solutions"* - an edit introducing a short extra sentence that adds some clarity or pertinent extra information to an answer is like to be considered useful and legitimate. Of course, "adding explanations" is a broad enough notion that it could potentially encompass radical transformations of an answer - like adding 6 paragraphs of exposition to somebody's one-line code-only answer - which are generally considered inappropriate. There's no bright line.

Comment: Looks like in response to my (now-deleted) comment on the question, the asker has unaccepted your answer and deferred the choice of which answer should end up at the top of the page to the voters - which seems like a fine outcome to me.

Comment: @MarkAmery thanks for the edit. Just that I don't feel that there is any need to unaccept jp_data_analysis's answer, though. As jadsq said, his/her answer is good. But let bygone be bygone...

Comment: @Tai FWIW, I agree that there was no *need* for the answer to be unaccepted. Both answers are valid; neither is totally superior to the other. I only suggested it to the asker because jp_data_analysis had expressed that it was the outcome he wanted; I wouldn't've done so otherwise.

Comment: @MarkAmery I understood. yet let's follow what we believe next time lol

Answer (score 5):

While copying and pasting another user's answer into one's own answer shouldn't be done, there are, in my opinion, valid times to change and improve your answer based on a newer one to the same question.

Here are a couple of examples that come to mind:

1. **The API changes.** I have quite a few answers in the Swift tag, which is fairly new and the API often changes. Rather than just leave my old answers forever in an old deprecated API state, I update them. Sometimes the reminder to update comes from seeing a newer answer. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34785349/3681880) is an example I updated based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41488326/3681880). I actually would have preferred to do something close to a copy/paste, but instead I just wrote a summary of the updated API.
2. **The answer by the other user isn't as good as it could be.** Sometimes another user adds an improved answer but doesn't clearly explain it. I think it is valid to incorporate the idea into your answer if you make further improvements to it. I rewrote the idea expressed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34733798/3681880) into [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34082979/3681880) because I felt that that user's answer was a little hard to follow.