# Can / should we do something about answer cannibalization?

Tags: discussion, answers, plagiarism

This question is not about copy pasting Stack Overflow questions to essays or assignment. Please read it before marking it as duplicate.

### Problem at a glance

Sometimes, users that own the top answer on a popular question "cannibalize" (copy paste in most cases) secondary answers content into theirs, hogging all the points.

This behaviour might end up demotivating people from improving existing  answer or update outdated solutions.

### Considerations

We have two perspectives to consider

#### 1. Person who seek answer

From his perspective it could be better to find the best answer on top without waiting the natural process for the new answer to overcome the old one

#### 2. Person who provide the alternative answer

If at all we accept that points motivate users to provide better or alternative answers, then as a consequence, allowing "cannibalization" could demotivate those user, slowing down the rate at which answers get updated or improved.

### Question

Not looking for a solution just yet, just trying to understand if that's just ok, or a minor problem occurring only in few cases, so my question are:

- Do you think this could actually lead to demotivating user to post new answers if they find existing one obsolete or unsatisfactory?
- What is the scale of the problem? Are there many answers affected?

Comment: This carries the assumption that the edit is done in bad faith.  Are you sure that it's done intentionally?  Or might it be a misunderstanding of how SE works?

Comment: @fbueckert true, but the fact that sometimes it's done unintentionally doesn't solve the underlining problem.

Comment: Do you have any examples of this happening?

Comment: @il_raffa: exactly how is that a duplicate?

Comment: Today in "Editing to explain why my question is not a duplicate is futile."

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, editing your question to state that it's not a duplicate, rather than explaining how the duplicate fails to answer your question, is in fact futile.  Telling people that they didn't read your question doesn't make your question any less of a duplicate, or make people any less likely to mark it as such.

Comment: @Servy: The author of this question didn't just say "This is not a duplicate." They specifically said that this isn't about plagiarizing content from here to an academic paper. And someone voted it as such *anyway*. *That's* what makes it futile. (And for that matter - chastising the reader aside - that statement wasn't even necessary to begin with, since neither the title nor body even remotely suggest that it was about the same. It's akin to prefacing "Are strings value types or reference types in C#?" with "This is not about Java, please don't close it as a duplicate of a Java question.")

Comment: (You'd have to be paying as little attention as a robo-reviewer to associate a C# string question with a Java string question just because it's about strings - and the fact that the usual Meta robo-reviewers contributed to the closure of this question says a lot.)

Comment: @BoltClock If you think that the question is clearly not a duplicate without an edit, then just say that, rather than saying that editing a post to explain why it's not a duplicate is futile, given that that's not the relevant action there.  Additionally I think the main reason it's not a duplicate is because the other question has a pretty bad answer, a good answer to that question could plausibly and this question.  Of course, it not existing makes the questions not duplicates.

Comment: @Servy: I don't need to repeat what others have stated - and my statement is meant to be in solidarity with frustrated users who take measures (preemptive as in this case or otherwise) to make it clearer that their questions aren't duplicates only for their questions to get incorrectly closed *anyway*.

Comment: @BoltClock And my statement is meant to indicate that if people want to edit their question to indicate that it's not a duplicate they should be doing so to actually explain how the question is different, not to insult people for casting a close vote that they think is wrong (even if I agree it's wrong).  I'd also like to hope that users, and moderators as well, would strive to keep discourse around the closure of questions professional, polite, and assuming that others are acting in good faith, even if you disagree with their actions, rather than being rude to them.

Comment: As an aside, it's interesting to note whose answer the above question was asked about.

Comment: @SamHanley, As an aside, it's interesting to note [my answer to that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362722/9209546). I have nothing to hide.

Comment: @jpp I don't mean to suggest you're hiding anything - I just thought that the fact that this is a discussion you've been a key part of in the past was interesting incidental context to your puzzling answer to this thread.

Comment: @SamHanley, Well, you certainly missed the sarcasm. Maybe you also missed my previous related question: [What are the criteria for plagiarism?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370432/what-are-the-criteria-for-plagiarism)

Comment: Are you really talking about literal copy/paste actions, or about cases where someone sees another answer and thinks _"hey, I hadn't considered that, let me update my answer to address that point as well"_ and then proceeds to write their own answer that gives the 'same' answer but formulated differently?

Answer (score 2):

There are two cases here.  Either the answer is plagiarizing other answers with its content, or it's not.

If it's plagiarizing others' content, either by not properly citing the work of others, or by merely copying large portions of others' work without incorporating it into their own original work, then flag the post for moderation attention and explain why you think the post is plagiarism.

If the post isn't plagiarizing, and is merely using another's work in a transformative way to improve on it in their own original answer, then that's a good thing, and very in line with the site's goals.  The site uses a very permissive license very intentionally, and very publicly.  It should be *expected* that when you're publishing content on SO for others, both on the site and off, to be using it and republishing it.  People who are strongly opposed to others doing so (as long as they follow the license terms) are going to run into all sorts of problems, because they have a core value that simply conflicts so strongly with the site's intended design.

Additionally, not every answer using the work of another is necessarily better.  If you feel that a post incorporates another's content, but doesn't do so in a way that meaningfully improves on it, then *reflect that opinion with your vote*.

Comment: The problem not addressed is `If it's plagiarizing others' content`. From experience, under current guidelines anything but a *precise* copy-paste job is not deemed plagiarizing. Whether an answer is plagiarizing is not, as you seem to imply, some unequivocal fact. If in doubt, we must assume good intentions!

Comment: @jpp Assuming good intentions doesn't mean nothing is plagiarism.  It just means there's an underlying presumption that one needs to have evidence to actually outweigh.  That you need *some* evidence that the user didn't independently arrive at an alternate solution isn't an impossible barrier to overcome.

Answer (score -8):

## Copying parts of answers is fine

This is the moderation line, as we are asked to assume good intentions, so let's put it in bold. In practice, it means anything that is not a word-for-word copy is acceptable. Change some variable names and you're good to go!

The usual wording that goes along with this:

> We only handle plagiarism cases that are clear attempts to copy
> content from another source rather than simply original work that
> demonstrates the same idea(s).

The counter-argument comes up at regular intervals:

1. [Plagiarism policy - how much of an answer can be copied to another answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294948/plagiarism-policy-how-much-of-an-answer-can-be-copied-to-another-answer)
2. [What are the criteria for plagiarism?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370432/what-are-the-criteria-for-plagiarism)

Comment: It's interesting (but wholly understandable) that people are happy to downvote when no alternative answers exist. Of course, it's a tongue-in-cheek answer bemoaning my own experience. Technically, however, it's correct and backed by examples.

Comment: No, it's not correct, and no, it's not backed by examples.  The policy, of which you've linked to, isn't that it's okay to copy other people's solutions if you just change a few variable names.  Your example merely states that for really trivial solutions it's common for different people to independently come up with the same, or a very similar, solution.  The example is saying that the differences observed there indicate that the other user independently arrived at the same solution, rather than copying it (with or without meaningless changes).

Comment: @Servy `indicate` is a strong word and inaccurate. `adjudged to have been independently arrived at..` is better, but (as you conveniently omit) still backed by the `assume good intentions` principle.

Comment: That still doesn't make your statement that it's okay to copy anything so long as you change a few variables.  That can clearly still indicate plagiarism, even when assuming good intentions.